# How do I create a Django model field that evaluates based on other fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'll try to describe my problem with a simple example. Say I have items of type `Item` and every item relates to a certain type of `Category`. Now I can take any two items and combine into an itemcombo of type `ItemCombo`. This itemcombo relates to a certain category called `ComboCategory`. The `ComboCategory` is based on which categories the items relate to, therefore I'm not to keen on hardcoding the `combocategory` in `ItemCombo` in case the items categories would change. Can I somehow make `combocategory` a virtual field in `ItemCombo` that evaluates just in time?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class Item(models.Model):
    value    = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


class ComboCategory(models.Model):
    category1 = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    category2 = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class ItemCombo(models.Model):
    item1         = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    item2         = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    combocategory = models.ForeignKey(ComboCategory)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your model classes are full Python classes, so you can add attributes, methods, and properties to them:

```
class ItemCombo(models.Model):
    item1         = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    item2         = models.ForeignKey(Item)

    @property
    def combocategory(self):
        return .. # some mumbo-jumbo of item1 and item2
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't solve the problem because I'm not able to do queries this way, for instance filtering all combos of a certain combocategory.

Comment: Yes, that's right, you can't query on this property.  Queries are done against data stored in the database, in the form of fields.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can only do queries on fields that are stored in the database. Now you should look at [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) for a way to evaluate your ItemCombo just in time and do filtering on it.